# Correct way to push data in AngularJs scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

This is the scope format I have

```
    $scope.order.Transaction{
    'source': value,
    'fees': value,
    'ref':value
   }
```

How do I push the above data to existing $scope,can anyone please guide me in the right direction?   This is what $scope.order.Transaction already contains:
    Object {source: "value", fees: "33", ref: "37226"}
I want to push a new object to it.How to do it?

Comment: It's JavaScript, nothing to do with angular

Comment: Need a bit more info to be able to help. What is the existing Transaction? Is it an array of objects? Are you trying to add (push)  a new object to it?

Comment: I have added more info,thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$scope.order.Transactions = [];

$scope.order.Transaction = {
    'source': value,
    'fees': value,
    'ref':value
};

$scope.order.Transactions.push($scope.order.Transaction);
```

Answer (score 1):

Its an javascript thing not an angular

```
$scope.order.Transaction.source = 'someValue'
$scope.order.Transaction.fees = 'someValue'
$scope.order.Transaction.ref = 'someValue'
```